# Snowflake Masking policy: replace int column by '*****'

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, masking, snowflake-schema

I'm using the snowflake masking policy to hide value from unauthorized role, but I can't find how replace int column by '*****'. I can replace it with `null`, but using this can be confusing (not knowing if it is really null or just hide).

The policy I'm using to replace int column by null:

```
create or replace masking policy values_mask as (val int) returns int ->
  case
    when current_role() in ('ADMIN') then val
    else null
  end;
```

How I apply the policy:

```
alter table databse.schema.table modify column value set masking policy values_mask;
```

I'm want else to retrun '****'. I have tried returns string or other similar change. But afterwards It creates errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output data type must match input data type:

[CREATE MASKING POLICY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-masking-policy.html#parameters):

> RETURNS arg_type_to_mask
>
> **The return data type must match the input data type of the first column that is specified as an input column.**
>
> ...
>
> **Currently, Snowflake does not support different input and output data types in a masking policy,** such as defining the masking policy to target a timestamp and return a string (e.g. ***MASKED***); the input and output data types must match.

---

The value `'****'`(string) is definitely not a valid integer value(column data type), therefore masking policy with requested signature will not work.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, in this case by what would replace the value to hide ? To avoid being confusing for the user.

Comment: @user15915737 The value should be neutral - NULL or outside the column domain.